# Push field to each element of object array (MongoDB)

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Let's say I have some documents of such type:

```
{ 
 _id: ObjectId("5abe0f5add80a30001eff68d"),
 obj_array: [ 
     { 
       a: 1,
       b: "some", 
       c: 134
     },
     { 
       a: 2, 
       b: "aaa",
       c: 564
     }
   ]
}
```

What I need to do is to update all the `obj_array` elements by **pushing a new field** `d: "new_value"`. Expected result:

```
 { 
 _id: ObjectId("5abe0f5add80a30001eff68d"),
 obj_array: [ 
     { 
       a: 1,
       b: "some", 
       c: 134,
       d: "new_value"
     },
     { 
       a: 2, 
       b: "aaa",
       c: 564,
       d: "new_value"
     }
   ]
}
```

I didn't find any other solution but constructing new `obj_array` object and setting `doc.obj_array` with the new array. I wonder is there some more elegant way to do that?
Here's my code:

```
myTable.find().forEach(function(document) {
    var new_array = [];
    document.obj_array.forEach(function(elem) {
        elem.d = "new_value";
        new_array.push(elem);
    })
    myTable.update({_id: document._id}, {$set: {obj_array: new_array}})
})
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use  [**`$[]`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/) the all positional operator which updates all the elements in an array

```
myTable.update(
  { "_id": document._id },
  { "$set": { "obj_array.$[].d": "new_value" }}
)
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1: run command npm install async --save

```
db.collection.find({_id:ObjectId("5abe0f5add80a30001eff68d")},function(err, result){
   if(result){
     async.eachSeries(result.obj_array,function(value, cb){
       value.d = "new_value";
       return cb();
     },function(){
       console.log(result)
     })
   }
})
//Once you get perfect result you can execute update query
db.collection.update({_id:ObjectId("5abe0f5add80a30001eff68d")},result)
```

> NOTE: If you work with nodeJS then you need to install async, if you
>   work with core javascript then you can change to common for-each loop.
>
> **its always work for me :)**

Answer (score 1):

You can simply achieve this by traverse array through `$[]` and update it:

for single update:

`db.getCollection('test').update({},{ "$set": { "array.$[].key": "Value" }})`

multiple updates:

`db.getCollection('test').updateMany({},{ "$set": { "array.$[].key": "Value" }})`